# Symfony Custom Validator not loading Dependency

Tags: php, symfony

## Error:

```
...ThemeValidator::__construct() must be of the type array, null given...
```

For some reason the Service is not being called, but the Class is being loaded directly.

## validation.yml

```
theme:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - DashboardHub\Bundle\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ThemeValidator: ~
```

## Validator Class

```
<?php
namespace DashboardHub\Bundle\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ThemeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

protected $config;

public function __construct(array $config)
{
    $this->config = $config;
}

public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'theme.validator';
}

public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    var_dump($this->config); exit;
}
// ...
```

## service.yml

```
dashboardhub_app_main.validator.constraints.theme:
   class: DashboardHub\Bundle\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ThemeValidator
   arguments: ["%dashboard_hub_app%"]
   tags:
     - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: theme.validator }
```

## Edit

```
parameters:
  dashboard_hub_app:
    themes:
        Github: DashboardHubAppBundle:Template:Github.html.twig
        GithubTravis: DashboardHubAppBundle:Template:GithubTravis.html.twig
```

## Edit2

It works find when used in the Form Service

```
dashboardhub_app_main.form.type.dashboard:
  class: DashboardHub\Bundle\AppBundle\Form\DashboardType
  arguments: ["%dashboard_hub_app%"]
  tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: dashboard }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I followed the docs, I can't see why it is not load the dependency (injecting the config as specified in the service.yml)

Comment: @EddieJaoude is `dashboard_hub_app` your service name?

Comment: @PeterPopelyshko no, thats my parameters. I updated above & included the parameters.

Comment: @EddieJaoude ok than, i don't understand what are you trying to inject into your Validator class, can you explain?

Comment: @PeterPopelyshko I want to inject the config/parameter data into the Validator class. Because it needs to validator that one of these options is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters:
  dashboard_hub_app: -- !!!!! IS NULL yes
```

funny :)
parameters follow one by one, so you need to be careful, `paramenters && themes` - are different.

to inject an array you need provide a value for this paramenter, but i guess you need to inject this one

```
themes:
    Github: DashboardHubAppBundle:Template:Github.html.twig
    GithubTravis: DashboardHubAppBundle:Template:GithubTravis.html.twig

arguments: ["%themes%"]
```

and result will be an array inside your Validator class

```
array (size=2)
  'Github' => string 'DashboardHubAppBundle:Template:Github.html.twig' (length=47)
  'GithubTravis' => string 'DashboardHubAppBundle:Template:GithubTravis.html.twig' (length=53)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand?

Comment: `dashboard_hub_app` works when I used it in the FormType Service (please look at the update, Edit2 above)

Comment: @EddieJaoude you are getting this error `must be of the type array, null given` - so your `dashboard_hub_app` is empty or containing null value

Comment: It is not empty, because it works for the form service. I don't think the Service is being loaded for the validator, but the class is being called directly - the alias definitely match. If I change it to `themes`, I get another error...The service "dashboardhub_app_main.validator.constraints.theme" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "themes".

Comment: would it be easier if i commit the code to a branch on github? I feel we are not on the same page at the moment, but I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Here is the code if easier? https://github.com/DashboardHub/PipelineDashboard/tree/feature/45-default-dashboard-custom-validator

Comment: Really? With making a change to the code or without making a change?